spresenseの初期起動時にpinがhighになってしまうため安全装置のリレーが使えません。。
現在、spresenseにセンサとリレーをつけて安全センサを組んでおります。
リレーがhighで安全センサがONとなります。
しかしながら、spresenseに電源が投入されると、数秒後にすべてのpinがHIGHになるので、リレーがONしてしまいます。（ちなみにarduinoは起動時もLOWのままです）
spresense起動時のpinがHIGHになってしまうのを止める方法はありますでしょうか？

spresenseってのは使ったことはありませんが、
その手の組み込み用のMPUのGPIOピンは、電源投入時には、ほぼ例外なくハイインピーダンスとなります。
電源投入時にすべてHighとなる、のであれば、
・初期プログラムで、ピンをHighにするコードが組み込まれている
・外部回路で、プルアップするなどしてHighになるように回路が組んである
ってことが考えられます
まずは、回路図をチェックして、Highにしてるようなところはないか、また、現在組み込まれているプログラムをチェックして、GPIOをHighにしているコードがないか、をチェックしてみよう
